# Why should glass harm a fext?

Tags: slavic, monsters

Why should glass bullets and other odd items (usually not used as ammunition) harm a [fext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fext)?

A fext is a revenant that is impervious to most damage, superman style, but glass it its kryptonite, why?

Comment: One of the interesting things about the firearms of the time--musket and arquebus, is that you could load them with non-standard ammunition, such as rocks, buttons and nails.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps non-translucent materials suitable for use as projectiles reflect the person's intention back on him who wishes to harm the fext, and glass, which is translucent, does not? One would have a neat pair of binary opposites here: metaphorically reflective and non-reflective, and physically non-translucent and translucent.

This is just a guess. It could also be something to do with the amount of knowledge that has gone into making the glass, especially if it is a special kind. As [an amorphous or non-crystalline solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_solid), glass is weird - it is practically [its own state of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter#Glass) - and this too might be relevant, analogously to the "neither day nor night" nature of twilight.

Answer (score 0):

Per the linked wikipedia article, the Fext rose with the advance of the gun as the primary weapon of war, in the 17th century.

The gun certainly was transformative; it was power, in a form that the everyman could grasp; it allowed anyone with even a moderate amount of training to overcome the prior pinnacle of military power, the armored knight; the fact that it could overcome a millennia of society tradition makes it exactly the sort of thing that could reach across and harm the supernatural as well.

Note also, that the fext was not alone in having a weakness to a specific type of firearm ammunition; at the same time, the werewolf, an ancient creature, gained its weakness to "silver bullets", and similarly, the Brothers Grim have an otherwise bulletproof witch slain with silver bullets.

Lore often simplifies or changes details over time and place. Other werewolf lore has werewolves that can be slain by normal lead bullets, provided that the lead was taken from a church's stain glass window. This is a specific case of the trope of "holy hurts evil", which could also be the origin of the fext's vulnerability: Church glass as the original requirement, later extended to all glass.